# Field in required a bean of type that could not be found consider defining a bean of type in your configuration

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm getting the following error when trying to run my app:

> Field edao in com.alon.service.EmployeeServiceImpl required a bean of
>   type 'com.alon.repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not be found.
>
> The injection point has the following annotations:
>
> - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)
>
> Action:
>
> Consider defining a bean of type
>   'com.alon.repository.EmployeeRepository' in your configuration.

Project structure:

[image]

EmployeeRepository:

```
package com.alon.repository;

import com.alon.model.Employee;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import java.util.List;

@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository {
    List<Employee> findByDesignation(String designation);
    void saveAll(List<Employee> employees);
    Iterable<Employee> findAll();
}
```

EmployeeServiceImpl:

```
package com.alon.service;

import com.alon.model.Employee;
import com.alon.repository.EmployeeRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class EmployeeServiceImpl implements EmployeeService {
    @Autowired
    private EmployeeRepository edao;

    @Override
    public void saveEmployee(List<Employee> employees) {
        edao.saveAll(employees);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<Employee> findAllEmployees() {
        return edao.findAll();
    }

    @Override
    public List<Employee> findByDesignation(String designation) {
        return edao.findByDesignation(designation);
    }
}
```

MyApplication:

```
package com.alon;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplicataion {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplicataion.class, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: Without an implementation the `EmployeeRepository` won't be available. Create an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have added spring-boot tag I guess you are using sprig data jpa. Your repository interfaces should extend `org.springframework.data.repository.Repository` (a marker interface) or one of its sub interfaces (usually `org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository`) for instructing spring to provide a runtime implementation of your repository, if any of those interfaces are not extened you'll get

> bean of type 'com.alon.repository.EmployeeRepository' that could not
>   be found.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you try to use spring data JPA. What you can check / debug is:

- Is `JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration` executed? You can see this in the start up log in the debug log level
- Does something change if you addionally add `@EnableJpaRepositories` with the corresponding basepackages.
- Add `@ComponentScan` with the corresponding packages, normally `@SpringBootApplication` should do it, but just in case.

you can also check the autconfig documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-auto-configuration.html

EDIT: see comment from @ali4j: I did not see that it is the generic spring Repository interface and not the spring data interface

regards,WiPu